# How to get user store domain by admin services?

Tags: wso2-identity-server

I want get user's domainstore from username so
`FrameworkUtils.prependUserStoreDomainToName(username)`
in identity.application authentication.endpoint, how to do it?

Can I use an admin service for it?

Comment: [What have you tried so far?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)
Please [edit] your question to show a [mcve] of the code
that you are having problems with, then we can try to help
with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

Does the username already contain the domain name ? Like ABC/username ?

If so you can use the util method in [1] to retrieve the domain name.

[1] https://github.com/wso2/carbon-kernel/blob/4.4.x/core/org.wso2.carbon.user.core/src/main/java/org/wso2/carbon/user/core/util/UserCoreUtil.java#L710